# jQuery select first element that has a certain class after this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/wxWgG/4/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p class="click">Click 1</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="target">Target 1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="target">Target 2</p>
</div>


<div>
    <p class="click">Click 2</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="target">Target 3</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="target">Target 4</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
   $(this).nextAll('.target').css('color','red');
});​
```

I need it so when you click a `p.click`, the next `p.target` turns red.

So if you click on `'Click 1'` then `'Target 1'` turns red. If you click on `'Click 2'` then `'Target 3'` turns red.

As well as `.find` I've tried `.closest` and from the jQuery documentation it seems to me like it should work. As you can see from the HTML,  `.target` is not a child of `.click`, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: nextAll works on the siblings, not outside its parent. So you need to tell us how you want to traverse.. if you want parents sibling child then it is possible.

Comment: Your example is not very good, it only contains one "Click" element. How are "Click"s and "Target"s associated? Are they both in order, meaning if the second "Click" is clicked, should the second "Target" be highlighted, etc. ? *edit:* apparently you linked to the wrong fiddle. That's why you should always include the code as well.

Comment: I don't see a `Click 1` or a `Click 2`.  Is your code up to date?

Comment: +1 for responding to the criticism of the initial post :)

Comment: Do you want 'Click 1' to highlight 'Target 1' & 'Target 2' or just Target 1? You are using `.nextAll` from which I assumed that you want to highlight all `.target` between 2 divs that has `.click`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is another approach, although I don't know how performant `.index()` is in this case. This also assumes that there are never two consecutive `.click` elements (or phrased differently: There is always at least one `.target` element between two `.click` elements):

```
var $elements = $('.click, .target');

$('.click').click(function() {
   $elements.eq($elements.index(this) + 1).css('color','red');
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxWgG/23/)

This works because the elements are selected in the order they appear in the document.

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for this?

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $(".target", $(this).parent().next()).css('color','red');
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxWgG/19/)

Comment: This works, but it breaks if I add another div around the div that contins p.click. I think i understand why this is happening, but is there a way of finding the next element with a certain class, regardless of how nested it is?

Comment: Your HTML would have to have a fixed structure or you have to define very clearly what cases you want to be covered. jQuery can't read mind :) As long as you can define the layout, there would be a way but the definition hast to be consistent and precise.

Answer (score 3):

This selects the elements you need in your html code:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
   $(this).parent("div").next('div').find('.target').css('color','red');
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated HTML, I created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wxWgG/22/

...and used this jQuery

```
$('.click').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().next().find('p.target').css('color','red');
});​
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: This works, but it breaks if I add another div around the div that contins p.click. I think i understand why this is happening, but is there a way of finding the next element with a certain class, regardless of how nested it is?

Comment: Your HTML in the OP should state the HTML you want to work with! See Felix Kling's answer - that looks like it will be structure-agnostic. Otherwise, update the OP and await another raft of updated answers....

Answer (score 0):

You html construct doesn't facilitate to access till specific target. We can achieve what you want but the script will get complicated when you traverse in such a manner. Instead, add a grouping div which will make you script small and easy.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/wxWgG/20/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="group"> <!-- added grouping wrapper -->
<div>
    <p class="click">Click 1</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="target">Target 1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="target">Target 2</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
<div>
    <p class="click">Click 2</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
    <p>This should be ignored</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="target">Target 3</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="target">Target 4</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.click').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.group').find('.target').css('color','red');
});
```

---

`.nextAll` works on the sibling. In your case, it will look for all #click's sibling with class `.target`.

What you need is `parents -> sibling -> child`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/wxWgG/9/)

```
$('#click').click(function() {   
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.target').css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: Only the next `.target` should turn red. This makes all `.target` turn red

Comment: This works, but it breaks if I add another div around the div that contins p.click. I think i understand why this is happening, but is there a way of finding the next element with a certain class, regardless of how nested it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    var go = true;

    var item = $(this).parent();

    while(go && item) {
        var target = $('.target', item)[0];

        if(target != null) {
            go = false;
            $(target).css('color', 'red');
        }

        item = $(item).next()[0];
    }
});​
```